# ggplot2: yearmon scale and geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts

More than a solution I'd like to understand the reason why something which should be quite easy, it's actually not.

[I am borrowing part of the code from a different post which touched on the issue but it ended up with a solution I didn't like]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

csvData <- "dt,status
2015-12-03,1
2015-12-05,1
2015-12-05,0
2015-11-24,1
2015-10-17,0
2015-12-18,0
2016-06-30,0
2016-05-21,1
2016-03-31,0
2015-12-31,0"

tmp <- read.csv(textConnection(csvData))
tmp$dt <- as.Date(tmp$dt)
tmp$yearmon <- as.yearmon(tmp$dt)
tmp$status <- as.factor(tmp$status)

### Not good. Why?
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = yearmon, fill = status)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_x_yearmon()

### Almost good but long-winded and ticks not great
chartData <- tmp %>%
  group_by(yearmon, status) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  as.data.frame()
ggplot(chartData, aes(x = yearmon, y = count, fill = status)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_yearmon()
```

The first plot is all wrong; the second is almost perfect (ticks on the X axis are not great but I can live with that). Isn't `geom_bar()` supposed to perform the count job I have to manually perform in the second chart?

**FIRST CHART**
[image: poor plot]

**SECOND CHART**
[image: better plot]

My question is: why is the first chart so poor? There is a warning which is meant to suggest something ("position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals") but I really fail to understand it.
Thanks.

**MY PERSONAL ANSWER**

This is what I learned (thanks so much to all of you!):

- Even if there is a `scale_#_yearmon` or `scale_#_date`, unfortunately *ggplot* treats those object types as continuous numbers. That makes `geom_bar` unusable.
- `geom_histogram` might do the trick. But you lose control on relevant parts of the aestethics.
- bottom line: you need to group/sum before you chart
- Not sure (if you plan to use ggplot2) *xts* or *lubridate* are really that useful for what I was trying to achieve. I suspect for any continuous case - date-wise - they will be perfect.

All in, I ended with this which does perfectly what I am after (notice how there is no need for *xts* or *lubridate*):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

csvData <- "dt,status
2015-12-03,1
2015-12-05,1
2015-12-05,0
2015-11-24,1
2015-10-17,0
2015-12-18,0
2016-06-30,0
2016-05-21,1
2016-03-31,0
2015-12-31,0"

tmp <- read.csv(textConnection(csvData))
tmp$dt <- as.Date(tmp$dt)
tmp$yearmon <- as.Date(format(tmp$dt, "%Y-%m-01"))
tmp$status <- as.factor(tmp$status)

### GOOD
chartData <- tmp %>%
  group_by(yearmon, status) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  as.data.frame()

ggplot(chartData, aes(x = yearmon, y = count, fill = status)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%h-%y"),
               breaks = seq(from = min(chartData$yearmon), 
                            to = max(chartData$yearmon), by = "month"))
```

**FINAL OUTPUT**
[image: final plot]

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference between the first and second plot. Can you post the images of your plots and point out what was wrong about the first plot?

Comment: Done as requested. Could it be some sort of issue on platform/package version? I am on WIN10; R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21); ggplot2 2.2.1

Comment: I would use instead: ggplot(tmp, aes(x = floor_date(dt, "month"), fill = status)) + 
  geom_bar() + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%b")), which gives  better x-axis.

Comment: `floor_date()` is from the _lubridate_ package, is it? Anyway: I get exactly the same result as per FIRST CHART above with that.

Comment: With ggplot2 3.3.0 it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You could also `aes(x=factor(yearmon), ...)` as a shortcut fix.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the first plot is screwed is basically `ggplot2` does not exactly what the `yearmon` is. As you see here it is just a `num` internally with labels.

```
> as.numeric(tmp$yearmon)
[1] 2015.917 2015.917 2015.917 2015.833 2015.750 2015.917 2016.417 2016.333 2016.167 2015.917
```

So when you plot without the previous aggregation, the bar is spread out. You need to assign appropriate `binwidth` using `geom_histogram()` like this:

```
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = yearmon, fill = status)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1/12) + 
  scale_x_yearmon()
```

`1/12` corresponds with 12 months in each year.

For a plot after aggregation, as @ed_sans suggest, I also prefer `lubridate` as I know better on how to change ticks and modify axis labels.

```
chartData <- tmp %>%
  mutate(ym = floor_date(dt,"month")) %>%
  group_by(ym, status) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  as.data.frame()

ggplot(chartData, aes(x = ym, y = count, fill = status)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m"),
               breaks = as.Date("2015-09-01") + 
                 months(seq(0, 10, by = 2)))
```